# I have to implement formula as one column in excel sheet

Tags: c#, vsto

```html
  public static void BuildSheetBody(string shtName, ref ListObject lo, DataTable dtSource)
        {
            try
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Entered RefData Body Hit");
                int RowCnt = dtSource.Rows.Count;

                Worksheet worksheet = Globals.Factory.GetVstoObject(Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[shtName]);
                if (worksheet == null)
                    throw new Exception("Worksheet can not be empty when building sheet body");

                //MessageBox.Show("Entered UnProtect Body Hit");
                UnProtect(worksheet);

                worksheet.Application.EnableEvents = false;
                worksheet.Application.ScreenUpdating = false;


                //MessageBox.Show("Defining Start Row Index Hit");

                if (lo != null)
                    worksheet.Controls.Remove(lo);
                for (int i = 0; i < Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[shtName].ListObjects.Count; i++)
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets[shtName].ListObjects.Item(i + 1).Delete();

                int rowStartIndex = 14;

                #region method 1
                // For Pivot Data
                Excel.Range lstObjRange = worksheet.Range["B" + rowStartIndex.ToString(), "V" + (rowStartIndex + dtSource.Rows.Count + 1).ToString()] as Excel.Range;
                lstObjRange.Clear();



                string listobjectname = "ListObject" + shtName;

                lo = worksheet.Controls.AddListObject(lstObjRange, listobjectname);

                string[] fields = new string[] { "Formula",
                                              "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
                                            };

                for (int i = 0; i < lo.ListColumns.Count; i++)
                {
                    lo.ListColumns[i + 1].Name = fields[i];
                }

                //MessageBox.Show("BInding Data Creation Hit");
                BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
                bs.DataSource = dtSource;
                lo.SetDataBinding(bs, "", fields);
                #endregion

                //MessageBox.Show("SetSlideDeckListObjectStyle Creation Hit");
                SetSlideDeckListObjectStyle(worksheet, rowStartIndex + 1, dtSource.Rows.Count);

                //MessageBox.Show("LockCorrespondCells Creation Hit");
                LockCorrespondCells(worksheet, dtSource);


                //MessageBox.Show("FormatCells Creation Hit");

                FormatCells(worksheet, dtSource.Rows.Count);



                // worksheet.Select(Type.Missing);
           
                worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = false;
                worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.SplitRow = 14;
                worksheet.Application.ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = true;
                worksheet.Activate();
                (worksheet.Range["A1", "A1"] as Excel.Range).ColumnWidth = 5;
                worksheet.Range["B18", "B18"].Select();
                worksheet.Range["B2", "B2"].Select();

                worksheet.Application.EnableEvents = true;
                worksheet.Application.ScreenUpdating = true;

                ProtectSheet(worksheet);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
             MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                return;
            }
        }
```

I am working with Excel Addin.I am using Vsto 2013 and excel 2016 version as tools for the development.
I have to implement formula as one column in excel sheet.
Here we want to get the formula from the frontend using c#.
The problem here is that i am unable to get the formula at the particular cell where i gave some formula, rather than it is showing all the cells in the formula format only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWHRN.png)

Comment: it would help if you show your code too

Comment: I am using the below line of code to unlock the particular Formula column "Excel.Range formularng = worksheet.Range["J" + startRowIndex, "J" + lastrowcnt] as Excel.Range;
                formularng.Locked = false;
                formularng.ColumnWidth = 10;"

Comment: I meant update the question with your code so it's formatted and everyone can see it...

Comment: Updated my question. Let me know if more information required.